# Sending a multiple push notifications at specific different times

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I'm struggling with sending multiple notifications at separate times. For example, I want to be able to send a push notification at 8:30, 9:00, 9:30 (for argument's sake) but it keeps sending a notification at the end. I really need saving. I thought sending push notifications would be much easier with Android.

This is my MainActivity.java code

```
package com.nerdoidis.localpushnotificationdemo;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> times;

    public void getTimes() {
        times = new ArrayList<>();
        times.add("5:25");
        times.add("5:26");
        times.add("5:27");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getTimes();

        for (int x = 0; x < times.size(); x++) {
            String time = times.get(x).toString();
            String[] timeSplit = time.split(":");
            int hour = Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[0]);
            int minute = Integer.parseInt(timeSplit[1]);

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            String formattedTime = df.format(c.getTime());
            String[] formattedTimeSplit = formattedTime.split(":");
            int hourNow = Integer.parseInt(formattedTimeSplit[0]);
            int minuteNow = Integer.parseInt(formattedTimeSplit[1]);

            if (hour > hourNow && minute > minuteNow) {
                //Do nothing for now
            } else {
                Notification notification = getNotification("Your Next Shuttle is at " +
                        times.get(x).toString());
                        scheduleNotification(notification, 1, hour, minute);
            }
        }



    }

    private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int id, int hour, int minute) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, id);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (this, id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

    private Notification getNotification(String content) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Shuttle Time");
        builder.setContentText(content);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        return builder.build();
    }
}

My "Broadcast Receiver" type class 

package com.nerdoidis.localpushnotificationdemo;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * Created by MarumoJohannesTsesan on 10/17/2017.
 */

public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
    }
}

Added it to the manifest as well with the following line 
        <receiver android:name=".NotificationPublisher" />
```

I'm still struggling though big time!

Comment: It keeps sending notification at the end means sending the notification at the time you specified? How about setting 10 min before the time you want to notify users?

Comment: Yes. Sending at the time specified. The idea is like that; to send 15 minutes before the time. However, I was still testing how to send multiple push notifications at specific times.